# Find if HashMap contains chosen value and return key

Tags: java

Is there any way to find if my `HashMap<String, String>` contains entry ( key,value) with value="x" and to go through all entries sequentially ?

Comment: Please take a look into Map interface first

Comment: If you change your question to mean the opposite, you should somehow mention that in your edited question or all the existing answers will look quite out-of-place.

Comment: [Possible duplicate: Detailed explanation given ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value

Answer (score 8):

[HashMap.containsKey()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29)

This is what `HashMap` is *made* for in the first place...

(Not sure what you mean by "to go through all entries sequentially", though. There's only 1 entry per key.)

---

Edit:

Now that you edited the question, the answer is *no*! :(

If you need that feature, design your own two-way `HashMap` that stores the location of each value in the other's value (hopefully that made sense), and then use that class. `HashMap`s aren't designed for this.

Answer (score 6):

There is the [`containsValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29) method, but for common implementations this just internally iterates through all values and compares them to the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern is to use

```
if(hashMap.containsKey(key)) {
    Object o = hashMap.get(key);

}
```

however if you know none of the values are `null` (Many Map collections do not allow null) then you can do the following which is more efficient.

```
Object o = hashMap.get(key);
if (o != null) {

}
```

BTW: containsKey is the same as

```
Set<Key> keys = hashMap.keySet();
boolean containsKey = keys.contains(key);
```

Comment: @Mehrdad, you are right, its containsKey, confused with Set. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use HashMap.containsKey() to know if it contains a given key.
Use HashMap.keySet() or HashMap.entrySet() to retreive the collection of entries or values and iterate sequentially on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the information you are looking for, but it would be inefficient:

```
Object key;
Object val;
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
for (Iterator iter = hm.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
  Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
  if (key.equals(e.getKey()) && val.equals(e.getValue())) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

As suggested in some of the other answers, you might consider a better data structure for the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to consider using a bidirectional map, such as the one in Google's Guava library: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html