# Iterate through map values with IF

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

For some reason I cannot get my iteration working. I have two classes, Cars and Garage.
I have `Map<Integer, Cars> cars = newHashMap<>();` within the Garage class and I want to iterate through all the Car objects in Map looking for a value of "Ford" and then print it out.

Any help/explanations would be great as very much a newbie.

```
private String model;
model = "Ford";

public void carMake() {
    for (Cars eachCar : cars.values()) {
        if (cars.containsValue(model)) {
            System.out.println("It is a ford");
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you ask something like `if (eachCar.model().equals(model))`?

Comment: `model` is a `String`, your map values are `Cars`

Comment: You're not even using the loop variable `eachCar`. Why?

Comment: show the `Cars` class and expand upon your description otherwise, your question is ambiguous.

Comment: Assuming class 
Car {
String model;
}
you should check either eachCar.getModel() equality to "Ford"

Comment: Thank you Akceptor, you've helped answer my question. Apologies if my explanation/question/terminology was not as clear as it should be as it's all still very new to me.

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted both garage and cars classes

Comment: Seems duplicate of stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230545/find-if-hashmap-contains-chosen-value-and-return-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it, supposing that class Car has a getModel() function that returns the car Model (Ford):

```
public void carMake() {
    for(Cars eachCar : cars.values()) {
        if("Ford".equals(eachCar.getModel()) {
             System.out.println("It is a ford");
        }
    }
}
```

In your code each interaction checks if your map (that contains Cars value) contains your model (that is a String). Even if you suppose that your model variable is a Car with model value = "Ford", each interaction you are checking the entire map, not the current value.