# Can I have a key-key map (as opposed to key-value) in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

What if I need to quickly search not only by the key but also by value. In other words, is there a construction like key-key as opposed to key-value?

Comment: Do notice that Guava's `BiMap` are basically two `Map`s put together and kept symmetric, so you could just do that yourself if you don't want to add an extra library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you want a *bimap* - I'd use the implementations in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) if I were you; there's a [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) interface, and various implementations such as [`HashBiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html) and [`ImmutableBiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableBiMap.html).

Note that you generally view a `BiMap` from one "side" (K1 to K2), and just call `inverse()` to get the opposite view of things (K2 to K1).

Answer (score 5):

Several libraries have something like that. For example, [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a `BiMap` (bidirectional map). Unfortunately there's no bidirectional map in the standard Java library.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you would have some sort of map with the following key:value pairs:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("foo", "Freddy");
map.put("bar", "Bobby");
```

Then, you would want to do map.get("foo") and get Freddy, or do map.get("Freddy") and get foo?

If so, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value) out.