# linked hashmap finding key by value?

Tags: java, hashmap, key

In a linked hashmap
Is there any methods to get the value of K by only providing V?
I've searched all over the internet and so far I've only found loops to get the key.

Comment: I think you have no other way except for loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value

Has the answers your looking for.

Comment: value cant be unique...so there is a possibility to get multiple keys for the same value.....

Answer (score 4):

No.

The point of a Map is to associate the V with a specific K, not the other way around. You would have to go through every K/V pair linearly (your loop).

If this is something that would be a common operation, you'd want to create a second map that went the other way (and probably wrap both in a class that abstracted that away). Of course the tricky bit is if you're not talking about unique values.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything that's better than a loop with a vanilla `LinkedHashMap`, but here are some alternatives with [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)...

If you know your values are unique, the [`BiMap`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap) [API](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) supports inverse lookups efficiently without having to maintain a backwards map by hand.  Use `HashBiMap` as your implementation, and you can look up a key from a value with `bimap.inverse().get(value)`.

If your values *aren't* unique, you could potentially build a `Multimap` that maps each value to each of its associated keys.  You could do this quickly using

```
Multimap<V, K> reverse = Multimaps.invertFrom(
  Multimaps.forMap(map),
  HashMultimap.<V, K> create());
```

which would let you look up all the keys associated with a value by using `reverse.get(value)`.

Answer (score 1):

A Map is not intended to be used this way, see @Brian Roach 's answer. You should consider replacing that Map by something else or consider reversing its key / values.

Anyway, you can find the keys corresponding to valueToFind have this way:

```
if (map.containsValue(valueToFind)) {
    for (final Object /* whatever you use, your 'K' type */ entry : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(entry) == valueToFind) {
            //You found one key containing valueToFind
            //Keep searching, there may be others
        }
    }
}
```