# Java Mapping Data Structure

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary, mapping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Hashmap: How to get key from value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value)

I am looking for a Java data structure (Some sort of map) in which I can perform a lookup on the Keys and the Values. For instance suppose I have a one to one mapping between a set of strings and integers. Call this object mapper. I would like to be able to perform the following:

1. `mapper.getAssociated(value)`:    This would return the key
2. `mapper.getAssociated(key)`:      This would return the value

Comment: there could be multiple keys with same value ? is this allowed.?

Comment: I think the answer to this question will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for google [guava BiMap](http://java.dzone.com/articles/guavas-bidirectional-maps) (or) commons [BidiMap](https://discursive.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=360750).

Example:

```
BidiMap bidiMap = new DualHashBidiMap( );
bidiMap.put( "il", "Illinois" );
bidiMap.put( "az", "Arizona" );
bidiMap.put( "va", "Virginia" );
// Retrieve the key with a value via the inverse map
String vaAbbreviation = bidiMap.inverseBidiMap( ).get( "Virginia" );

// Retrieve the value from the key
String illinoisName = bidiMap.get( "il" );
```

See this post for [BiMap Example](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/10/guavas-bidirectional-maps.html).

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using an implementation of [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) interface, for example [`HashBiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html). From the documentation:

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a map that preserves the
>   uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys. This constraint
>   enables bimaps to support an "inverse view", which is another bimap
>   containing the same entries as this bimap but with reversed keys and
>   values.

So given a `BiMap<Foo, Bar>` you can call [`inverse()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html#inverse%28%29) to return a `BiMap<Bar, Foo>` view.