# Get Index value of specific string in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, search, indexing

So I'm trying to get the PID (Process ID) of a certain app that's running on my phone.

What I'm doing first is:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pidsTask = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

for(int i = 0; i < pidsTask.size(); i++){
    nameList.append(pidsTask.get(i).processName + pidsTask.get(i).pid + "\n"); 

    }
```

This get's the name + PID from 'every' app that's running currently.

Now, I want to get the PID of a certain app name "Com.ExampleName".
Since the PID can/is Dynamic and can possibly change, I want it to be able to search the array for the name, get the position (i) and get the PID that belongs to that position (i).

How can I acomplish that?

Comment: why not use a map for this Key, Value (processName, ProcessID) pair?

Comment: Why not use a map instead of a List.... Map<PID, Name> and search the map based on the value instead of the key?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value

Answer (score 0):

The Map suggestion is good, but if you need to do it this way, you can loop through the list, and for each string check

```
if nameList.get(i).substring(0,appName.length).equals(appName) {
    String pidStr = nameList.get(i).substring(appName.length,nameList.get(i).length())
    int pid= Integer.parseInt(pidStr);
}
```