# How do I get out the corresponding key of the value in that HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, key

How do I print out the corresponding key of the value in that map? I don't think there's a getKey() method for a HashMap.

```
 Map <Integer, String > map1 = new HashMap <Integer, String> ();
         map1.put(7,"GREAT");
          map1.put(8,"Try Again!");

          if (map1.containsValue("GREAT")){        
             System.out.println(WHAT DO I PUT HERE?);

          }
```

Comment: Here is answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value

Comment: Don't. Fix your program so the map is the right way around. (If you still really want to do it, then you have to do it the boring way by looping over every entry in the map and checking the value.)

Comment: @immibis Thanks! That's what i did. Sometimes, just need a simple advise.

Comment: @Yubi Thanks, I read that as well. helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 Map <Integer, String > map1 = new HashMap <Integer, String> ();
     map1.put(7,"GREAT");
      map1.put(8,"Try Again!");
      Integer key=null;
      Set<Integer>keySet=new HashSet<Integer>();
      if (map1.containsValue("GREAT")){        
        keySet=map1.keySet();
        Iterator<Integer>iter=keySet.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            if(map1.get(key=iter.next()).equals("GREAT")){
                break;
            }
        }

      }
      System.out.println("Key is:"+key);
    }
```

Comment: Don't compare strings with ==.