# How to get the key of a Map based on the value

Tags: java

This is my program , could anybody please tell me how do i get Map's key based on the value .

I have tried as

```
String vendor_name = map.get("value");
```

But  its returing me null

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HashMap<String, String> for_highest_price_vendor = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for_highest_price_vendor.put("vendor1", "20");
        for_highest_price_vendor.put("vendor2", "25");
        String maxValueInMap = (Collections.max(for_highest_price_vendor
                .values())); // This will return max value in the Hashmap

        String vendor_name = for_highest_price_vendor.get(maxValueInMap);

        System.out.println(vendor_name);

    }

}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value

Comment: Mapping is one way, so you have iterate through all the keys to get the one you need (and we have assumed that K-V pairs are 1:1).

Comment: What if there are two different keys with the same value? Which key would you want to have?

Comment: instead of getting highest value first and then retrieve the vendor, iterate on map keep a tab on the highest price and its vendor.At the end of loop you will get your highest vendor. Ofcourse since more than one vendor can have same price, so save vendors having highest price in a list.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reverse mapping.

What you can do is iterate the entries and compare the values with your desired value, then get the key if it equals.

Of course, multiple keys can have an equal value!

For instance:

```
Map<String, String> foo = new HashMap<String, String>();
foo.put("foo", "bar");
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: foo.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().equals("bar")) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        break; // or not, you may want to add to a Collection and return it once the loop is completed
    }
}
```

Comment: And if the mapping is not 1:1 you have to take care of the same valued items!

Answer (score 1):

You can do manual iteration, or use one of [Apache Common Collections Libraries](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).

[`Interface BidiMap <K,V>`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html) is a bi-directional map, allowing you to map a key to a value and also to **map a value to a key** (using `getKey();` method).