# Is there a map<k, k> in java?

Tags: java

Is there any standard structure `Map<k1,k2>`? This means I can get the "value" through the "key" and the "key" through the "value". In other words both values and key are a Set connected to each other.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value). There is also an answer which shows how you can do it with the Java standard library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard library doesn't have one, but for example Guava has the [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).