# Java find all the key with specific value

Tags: java

is there a way to find out all the key which having same value in the map.
Like

```
map.put("A","Abc");
map.put("B","Abc");
map.put("C","Abc"); 
map.put("D","Bcd");
```

Here I want to find out all the key which having value "Abc".

Comment: Yes, there is - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value).

Answer (score 4):

*Find all "x", such that "y"* is called [`filtering`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(higher-order_function)).

This is how you can [filter using Java 8 Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
Stream<String> keys = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(x -> "Abc".equals(x.getValue()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

For Java 7, you have to do it manually:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet())
    if("Abc".equals(e.getValue()))
        keys.add(e.getKey());
```

Comment: Alright, I'll add a Java 7 example. But I think that you should upgrade to Java 8 asap!

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Guava filter.

```
Map<String, String> map = Maps.newHashMap();
map.put("A", "abc");
map.put("B", "abc");
map.put("C", "a3c");
map.put("D", "abc");
final String str = "a3c";
Map<String, String> filteredMap = Maps.filterEntries(map, new Predicate<Map.Entry<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(final Map.Entry<String, String> stringStringEntry) {
        return stringStringEntry.getValue().equals(str);
    }
});
```

This would return a Map of all the map entries which have `str` as a value.

FYI I only provided the function definition to show what it was doing however I would suggest using the predefined Predicates eg:

```
Map<String, String> filteredMap = Maps.filterValues(map, Predicates.equalTo(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. You can obtain a list of key-value pairs from the map. And then it's just a matter of filtering out the keys that map to your specific value.

Like so for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("A", "Abc");
    map.put("B", "Abc");
    map.put("C", "Abc");
    map.put("D", "Bcd");

    Set<Entry<String, String>> set = map.entrySet();//<-- get key-value pairs
    for(Entry<String, String> entry : set){//<-- iterate over all entries
        if(entry.getValue().equals("Abc")){//<-- check for your value
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());//<-- print the key / or add it to a list if you want
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps :)