# How i can extract and print specific values from a Hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

```
I have this code here : 
 public static void exercise5e() {
    List<Hills> hillist = Hills.readHills();
```

public static Map> hillsByCounty(List hills) {

```
    HashMap<String, Set<Hills>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Set<Hills>>();
    // List<Hills> hillist = Hills.readHills();

    for (Hills h : hillist) {
        String key = h.countryname;

        } else {
            Set<Hills> set = new TreeSet<Hills>();
            set.add(h);
            hashMap.put(key, set);

        }

    }





    System.out.println(hashMap1);
    return hashMap1;
}
```

}
My hashmap has values of ( hill name , country name , height, longitude and latitude from a list however i need to print only 3 counties with the first 3 hills of each counties and their height how can i do that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Hz7.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Hashmap: How to get key from value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383797/java-hashmap-how-to-get-key-from-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how your method should look like. I think that's the best one can do without the actual code.

```
    List<Hills> hillist = Hills.readHills();
    Map<String, Set<Hills>> hillsByCounty = Hills.hillsByCounty(hillist);

    Set<Map.Entry<String, Set<Hills>>> entrySet = hashMap.entrySet();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Set<Hills>>> entryIterator = entry1.iterator();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            Map.Entry<String, Set<Hills>> mapEntry = entryIterator.next();
            System.out.println("### County: " + mapEntry.getKey());
            Set<Hills> hills = mapEntry.getValue();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {     
                    Hill hill = iterator.next();
                    System.out.println(hill.hillName + " " + hill.height);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Change **hill.hillName** and  **hill.height** to whatever variable names for hill name and hill height are.

Comment: Should break out after 3 counties, since OP wants to print only 3 counties.

Comment: Well to be honest yes it is working but is not breaking after 3 counties , it is going until the end of the whole list

Comment: Simplest solution: add counter, and then after each iterator increment it and check if it = 3. I've edited my answer

Comment: I've changed it again so that it uses the iterator from the code you provided. I think that's what's expected of you.